# Why do I need a surrounding composable block in order to use a Modifier property without resulting in "Unresolved reference" error?

Tags: android, row

I'm in the process of working through Android Compose Unit 1->Pathway 3 (Build a Basic Layout) "Practice: Compose Basics" Codelab, [section 4. Compose quadrant](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-composables-practice-problems?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-1-pathway-3%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-composables-practice-problems#3), and I keep getting an error on play/build: Unresolved reference: weight when using only a Row layout block with Modifier.weight included. So I resorted to checking the [Solution code for MainActivity.kt](https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-practice-problems/blob/main/Unit%201/Pathway%203/ComposeQuadrant/app/src/main/java/com/example/composequadrant/MainActivity.kt), which surrounded this Row block with a Column block, and this builds fine. This is fine for me in moving on, but, for the sake of learning, I'm just wondering why the surrounding Column block is necessary, primarily because many answers on stackO suggested that Modifier.weight is supported in a Row or Column layout block on its own. Does anyone know the distinction here?
Here's my code (problematic functionality (ComposeRowWithWeightAndColumns) preceding the working functionality (ComposeColumnWithRowAndColumns)):

```
@Composable
fun ComposeRowWithWeightAndColumns(modifier: Modifier = Modifier)
{
    Row(Modifier.weight(1f)) { // ********** error pops here ***************
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            ComposeCard("Android0", "Body0", 0)
            ComposeCard("Android2", "Body2", 2)
        }
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            ComposeCard("Android1", "Body randomX", 1)
            ComposeCard("Android3", "Body random", 3)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ComposeColumnWithRowAndColumns(modifier: Modifier = Modifier)
{
    Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Row(Modifier.weight(1f)) { // ********** no error here ***************
            Column(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {
                ComposeCard("Android0", "Body0", 0)
                ComposeCard("Android2", "Body2", 2)
            }
            Column(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {
                ComposeCard("Android1", "Body randomX", 1)
                ComposeCard("Android3", "Body random", 3)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FYI: I'm running **Android Studio Hedgehog | version 2023.1.1 Patch 1** on a **Mac** running *Monterey Version 12.7.2*

Comment: "many answers on stackO suggested that Modifier.weight is supported in a Row or Column layout block on its own" - it is supported for *children of a Row and Column*. You seem to be applying the weight to the Row itself - what exactly were you expecting that to do?

Answer (score 1):

It requires a surrounding composable block because `Modifier.weight()` is not a single top-level extension function.

There are two different functions: [one](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/foundation/foundation-layout/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Row.kt#L140-L157) is a member function of `RowScope`, and the [other](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/foundation/foundation-layout/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Column.kt#L124-L146) is a member function of `ColumnScope`. Both are still extension functions for `Modifier`. The first one affects width of the *children* of `Row`, while the second affects height of those of `Column`.

This design implies that you can call `Modifier.weight()` only inside the corresponding context. In other words, in the place where you call it, `this` should be either `ColumnScope` or `RowScope`, which is valid inside the `content` lambda of the `Column()` and `Row()` functions, respectively. This ensures that the right one is picked, and none can be chosen outside.

Comment: It make sense in theory that this functionality would need a parent layout "host" (`Column`, in my example) so that the denominator for the weight percentage (one child size percentage = (one child weight float value) / (sum of child weight values) can be calculated from the sum of all weight calls of its children. I was thinking on a much lower level, before actually understanding how the property works. My bad. I need to remember to continue being a mathematician while learning new tech languages. Thanks, Vlad!